# How can Young's modulus be dimensionless, but still have units?

Tags: units, spacetime-dimensions, elasticity

[According to this wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_modulus#Units):

> Young's modulus is the ratio of stress, which has units of pressure, to strain, which is dimensionless; therefore, Young's modulus has units of pressure.

From my reasoning if something is dimensionless, it should be a unitless ratio. So how come Young's modulus has a unit?

Comment: Because that article has punctuation problems, will delete this question. Once you read this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Young's Modulus isn't dimensionless!

It says STRAIN is dimensionless (which is true).

SO Y = Stress/Strain = [Pressure]/[Dimensionless] = [Pressure]!

Young's Modulus has the same dimensions as that of pressure, which is:

$[M] [L]^{-1} [T]^{-2}$

And units of pressure, which is Pascal.

Comment: Hi mikhailcazi. Welcome to Physics.SE. This site uses an unique TeX markup style called MathJax. This markup is very useful for understanding math equations and parameters. Please have a look [here for an intro](http://www.math.harvard.edu/texman/) or our [FAQ](http://physics.stackexchange.com/faq#notation) for more info. For example, `$\theta$` results $\theta$, `$\omega$` inserts $\omega$, etc. It's quite interesting. You can revise your post if you can ;-)